# MySQLI PHP Session from database

Tags: php, mysql, session, mysqli

I'm doing an A Level Computing project and I want to create a session using a studentID stored in a database in order to display bits of information relating to users.

I can do it using other fields from the database but not the studentID field (the one that I need to use as it's a foreign key I'm using to link the tables I want to display the information from).

Would someone be able to have a look through what I've done and see if I'm doing anything wrong?  The code may not be the best but I'm new to all of this.

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","archtenapply");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "MySQLi Connection was not established: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = md5($_POST['pass']);
    $sql= "SELECT studentID FROM loginfo WHERE email ='$email' AND password= '$pass'";
    $run_user = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
    if($check_user>0){
        $_SESSION['studentid'] = $row{'studentID'};
        header("location: ../pages/hub.php");
    }else {
        header("location: ../errors/incorrectlogin.php");
    }

}
?>
```

Any help massively appreciated!

Comment: Are any errors being thrown?

Comment: `$row{'studentID'};` wrong bracket type. edit: and MD5? I hope this isn't going live. 2nd edit: `$row` won't do much, not without iterating over it and you're only assigning it to that, so that will fail for too many reasons.

Comment: You have just forgotten to actually get result row before you try and use it

Comment: this one's all yours @RiggsFolly ;-) too hot a question.

Comment: You are open to SQL injections, use prepared statements. @Fred-ii- curly or brackets work, `Both square brackets and curly braces can be used interchangeably for accessing array elements (e.g. $array[42] and $array{42} will both do the same thing in the example above).` http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php although I too prefer the square brackets.

Comment: You really shouldn't use MD5 password hashes and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security.

Comment: I stand corrected @chris85 *grazie* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks Ralph you are all heart

Comment: @RiggsFolly anytime.... so now we'll need to find you a Looney Tunes 'nick ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Oh I just cannot wait to see what you come up with??!?!?!?!?!? Be gentle with me I hurt easily

Answer (score 0):

See the one line addition to your code that actually gets the row you queried for, and the array syntax correction (thanks @Fred-ii-).

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","archtenapply");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "MySQLi Connection was not established: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = md5($_POST['pass']); // ***See note***
    $sql= "SELECT studentID FROM loginfo WHERE email ='$email' AND password= '$pass'";
    $run_user = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $check_user = mysqli_num_rows($run_user);
    if($check_user>0){

        // this get the result of the query as an assoc array into $row
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_user);

        // also fixed array syntax
        $_SESSION['studentid'] = $row['studentID'];
        header("location: ../pages/hub.php");
    }else {
        header("location: ../errors/incorrectlogin.php");
    }

}
?>
```

***NOTE***

PHP now has some much better ways to hash a password [See the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php)

Using MD5 to hash passwords with, is no longer a safe method to use.

It is recommend to use [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: I was just about to edit about passwords lol but I'll have to add to that... you'll see. Edit: *done* ;-)

Comment: Most welcome. I admit I took the easy way out on that one. There you go I am basically lazy, does that help with the nick'

Comment: it sure does, I'll get back to ya ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- ??The Genie ?? or the Bear

Comment: *Hm....* hadn't thought of that pick-ah-nick basket. Any which one; depends on how you feel that day. Hungry, or wishful, *or both*.